# what does the vs-code "JSON: Max Item Computed" setting actually do?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

### what does vs-codes *"JSON: Max Item Computed"* setting mean?

I received a notification from vs-code while viewing a JSON file specifying:

> "document symbols have been limited to 5000 items"

I didn't see any immediate change and assumed that symbols referred to the number of items/records in my JSON object until I looked at the JSON file and found that it contained over 10.000 items/records. I checked the description of this vs-code setting which stated that

> "The maximum number of outline symbols and folding regions computed (limited for performance reasons)."

this description just brings me back to not understanding what this setting is used for.

I'd like to know what this setting actually affects and what is meant by the following in JSON - with simple terms so my dumbass can understand:

- **document symbols**
- **outline symbols**
- **folding regions computed**

[Image of the vs-code notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KewpR.png)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62917867/what-should-i-set-for-json-maxitemscomputed-in-vs-code) link is to another stackoverflow question which only asked about the appropriate value to let this setting be, and brings up another point about **JSON language support** which only deepens my confusion.

[This](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84259) link also mentions the setting, but doesn't give clarity to what it does, and how it affects peoples work.

Comment: Essentially this is referring to the folding icons that allow you to minimize/expand parts of the json for read ability. It doesn't affect the actual content of the loaded file at all.

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Essentially this is referring to the folding icons that allow you to
> minimize/expand parts of the json for read ability. It doesn't affect
> the actual content of the loaded file at all.
> [code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/json](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/json)

– Victor Learned

Victor Learned's Comment Has Answered the question. Thank you